# How to compile ebitengine for a specific version of android?

Tags: go, gomobile, gomobile-android

In help to the command, the only line, it collects, as I understand it:

```
ebitenmobile bind [-target android|ios] [-bootclasspath ] [-classpath ] [-o output] [build flags] [package]
```

The minimum android version that I have is 19, the goal is 30-33, there is a place in the command for this `[build flags]`. I try like this but it doesn’t work:

```
./ebitenmobile bind -target android -javapkg my.game . -o . -androidapi 30
```

I tried to arrange them differently, the error is the same - version 16 was not found, so it does not see `-androidapi 30` / `-androidapi=30`, gomobile collects everything, yes, but they say that this is only for tests. If you run this application on the device, it will not work at all, or at least not normally.

How do I tell the team that I want to change the api version?

The main problem why I'm doing this is the error I get after installing and running the application stating that the version of the application is for an earlier version of android, even if you install an application with API 33 on Android 11 with API 30.

https://ebitengine.org/en/documents/mobile.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When reading your question, it seemed unclear if you are seeking guidance on how to contact the development team, or instead specify an API version to the command line tool.  Also, the opening statement of your post "In help to the command, the only line, it collects, as I understand it" is not very clear. Did you use a translator? Could you try and use a different translator?

Comment: Sure, i want instead specify an API version to the command line tool, i know what for gomobile i can use -target=android -androidapi=30, but how pass arguments for this command (ebitenmobile)?